# Does Ito's Isometry hold if the integrand has a brownian motion in it?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am wondering what is the distribution of:

$$
\int_0^tW_sdW_s
$$

**Solution**: (Thanks to @muaddib)

Applying Ito's Formula to $W_t^2$ gives $d(W_t^2) = 2W_tdW_t +dt$, and so:
$$
\int_0^tW_sdW_s= W_t^2 - t
$$
Since $W_t^2 \sim ~t Z^2$ where $Z\sim N(0,1) \implies Z^2 \sim \chi^2_1 $ , then:

$W_t^2 \sim \Gamma(\frac{1}{2},2t)$

Comment: You don't need the Ito Isometry to find the distribution of that integral.  Apply Ito's lemma to $f(W_t) = W_t^2$.

Comment: I get that $\int_0^t W_s dW_s = W_t^2 -t$. So since $W_t \sim N(0,t)$, then the distribution here is chi squared?

Comment: Right $W_t^2$ is, and subtract off the mean.

Comment: @muaddib so $W_t^2 \sim \Gamma (\frac{1}{2}, 2\sqrt{t})$, could you tell me what the distribution is when i subtract t ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a well known distribution, but you can just observe that if $X_t$ has that $\Gamma$ density then you can use $P(X_t - t > x) = P(X_t > x + t)$ to find the density.

Comment: "I know that stochastic integrals are normally distributed" Really?  Quite a novelty.

Comment: @saz why not make a constructive rather than sarcastic comment?